# Scrapy throws Attribute Error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

With the way I wrote code here I got results from different sites but for some reason this site throws error. As I'm a new coder in scrapy, I haven't got the capability to settle the issue myself. Xpaths are allright. I'm attaching what I see in the terminal along with the code:

items.py

```
import scrapy
class OlxItem(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Url = scrapy.Field()
```

olxsp.py

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule 
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class OlxspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "olxsp"
    allowed_domains = ['olx.com.pk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.olx.com.pk/']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="lheight16 rel homeIconHeight"]')),
             Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="fleft tcenter"]'),
             callback='parse_items', follow=True)]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        page=response.xpath('//h3[@class="large lheight20 margintop10"]')
        for post in page:
            AA=post.xpath('.//a[@class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink"]/span/text()').extract()
            CC=post.xpath('.//a[@class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink"]/@href').extract()
            yield {'Title':AA,'Url':CC}
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'olx'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['olx.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'olx.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

image of the terminal after scrapy done running:
[image]

Comment: Could you also post your Scrapy project settings? Also, make sure the tracebacks and errors you post are texts, not screenshots (which are not searchable). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your kind reply. I did nothing in settings.py, rather kept it as it is. Anyways, adding that too in the description.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True` which tells scrapy to check for the `robots.txt` file of the domains it crawls, so it can determine how to be polite to those sites.
2. You are allowing a different domain in `allowed_domains = ['www.olx.com']` than the one you are actually crawling. If you are only going to crawl `olx.com.pk` sites, changed the `allowed_domains` to `['olx.com.pk']`. If you don't actually know which sites you are crawling, just remove the `allowed_domains` attribute.

Comment: Thanks eLRuLL, for your response. Satisfying both the parameter according to your suggestion could not bring any result either.

Comment: Sorry to have not been around my pc. Now, it shows "wrapped Request object has no Attribute type. Attribute Error 14.

Comment: @SMth80 please copy all your log into a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) and share it here so we can check it correctly. Screenshots are not that helpful